# Help writing a stored procedure / SQL Query error

Tags: stored-procedures

I have table `tblcategory` with columns `categoryid , shopid , title, logicalcode`.

I have a second table `tblproduct` with columns `productid, shopid, producttitle ,price ,logicalcode , available`.

I have a third table `categoryproduct` with columns `categoryproductid, categoryid, productid`

I have a grid view for displaying products in a given category with columns `producttitle` and `logicalcode`.

I have written a stored procedure with input parameter as `categoryid` (mandatory) to get the list of products in that category:

```
@categoryid int
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT P.Title, P.LogicalCode 
  FROM tblProduct AS P 
  JOIN  tblCategory AS C  
  WHERE P.LogicalCode=C.LogicalCode AND
  WHERE C.CategoryID=@categoryid    
END
```

But I got the error near to "WHERE" condition

Would anyone please help me out?

Comment: is CategoryID an INT?  You obviously have two WHERE's which is wrong, but you mention below that you took one out and it still errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `WHERE` clauses. It should be:

`WHERE P.LogicalCode=C.LogicalCode AND
      C.CategoryID=@categoryid`

**EDIT**

OK, try

```
SELECT P.Title,P.LogicalCode  
FROM tblProduct P  
JOIN tblCategory C   
ON P.LogicalCode=C.LogicalCode  
WHERE C.CategoryID=@categoryid
```

Comment: No worries - it was the combination of two `WHERE`s and the bad `JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
SELECT P.Title,P.LogicalCode 
FROM tblProduct AS P JOIN  tblCategory AS C    
WHERE P.LogicalCode=C.LogicalCode 
AND  C.CategoryID=@categoryid
```

Comment: I got same error like this Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure uspCategoryFetch, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Comment: You also need to specify what you are joining P and C together with. For example .... FROM tblProduct P JOIN tblCategory C ON P.CategoryKey = C.ID .....